# To calculate the cube of using pow

Tags: c, pow

what is wrong with the code since it is not giving the value for cube

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main(){
int number;
printf("Give The Number:\n");
scanf("%d",number);

int cube;
cube = pow(number,3);
printf("Cube : %d/n,cube);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please check the compiler warnings. `scanf("%d",number);` should be `scanf("%d", &number);`. Using an 32-bit `int` will allow a maximum input of `1290`.

Comment: `printf("Cube : %d/n,cube);` I guess you are missing something here too.

Comment: Please enable and read all warnings that your compiler produces. In fact, the code as given doesn't compile as you are missing a closing quote on the `printf()`.

Comment: Also if you must convert back to `int` use `cube = (int)round(pow(number, 3));`.

Comment: What's wrong with `number*number*number`?

Answer (score 1):

you are not printing it. also when you post questions here also post the error that your code gives.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main(){
int number;
printf("Give The Number:\n");
scanf("%d", &number);

int cube;
cube = pow(number,3);
printf("Cube : %d", cube);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Sorry edited it.

Answer (score 1):

change

```c
scanf("%d",number);
```

to

```c
scanf("%d",&number);
```